# Can we carry 3 laptops from the USA to Germany?

Tags: customs-and-immigration, transit, germany, london, berlin

Can we carry three laptops from the USA to Germany? One is Lenovo Thinkpad, a MacBook Pro and a Dell. One is for my office work and the other two are personal.

I have a transit at London Heathrow airport and I'll be flying with British Airways.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If it's clear that the computers are for your personal use, and are reasonable, I don't see why you should have any problems.  One laptop per person is certainly reasonable these days, and having a second one for one of the travelers, given that it's a work machine, isn't at all crazy either.

If all three machines are brand new, in boxes, that sounds like you're importing them for resale :) but if these are clearly used, and the story makes sense, you'll be fine.

Comment: Remember though that there are limits on number/size of carry-on luggage, which may imply you will need to have at least some of them in checked luggage, with the associated risks. And you should think about setting up VMs or dual boot :-)

Comment: I have had a mobile phone and a discardable camera stolen from checked luggage, and even a computer sent from Portugal to Compaq Germany via airplane stolen.  Compaq gave me a new one as replacement...It is a very bad idea to check in valuables. Some airlines allow for 1 hand bang for males, and 2 for women. Or put 2 computers in the same bag, you are usually allowed 7kg.

Comment: Well, I'm also thinking to put one laptop in checked luggage. Although, I have 23kgs allowed in carry-on luggage. I'm not sure if I should put all three of them in carry on luggage or not. Two of them I bought from US but of course for my personal use.

Comment: @Jim MacKenzie: On german custom site they say, we cannot take goods of more than 430 euros even if it is personal or gifted. I have bought two laptops from US which are more than 430 Euros, So can it cause any problem?

Comment: @s-rupali I'd trust the German Customs site.  It's possible you can bring more goods, but you may have to pay tax and/or duty on them.

Comment: @Jim MacKenzie I'm not carrying them packed, because they are for personal use. I'm not sure if the duty still applicable.

Comment: @s-rupali Usually you can import any reasonable amount of property that you will be re-exporting with you, tax- and duty-free, but it depends on the country.

Comment: The 430 Euro limit is for things you actually import into the country. If you come to visit and bring stuff with you for your own use, and take it back out, that's not _importing_ as such. Your clothes alone together with your suitcase will be worth more than 430 Euro. Only stuff that remains in Germany is affected by that limit.

Comment: @simbabque, It makes sense. Thank you. Btw when I landed in Germany, they didn't ask me anything.. even they didn't ask me to fill any immigration form. Although I bring just 2 laptops with me so I was good.

Comment: @s-rupali immigration is not customs. That has nothing to do with your laptop. Or did you not have clothes with you? That might be suspicious.

Comment: @simbabque, sorry I made a typo. I meant, they didn't ask me to fill custom form (where we usually fill value of goods). I was having clothes. :)